# Print xaringan slides with presenter notes

Tags: r, xaringan, remarkjs

Is it possible to print xaringan slides with the presenter notes?

I know I can print the slides using these methods (https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/wiki/Export-Slides-to-PDF). But I can't get a print out with the presenter notes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Today I have had a same problem.

I have made this solution.

Only "basic" CSS - you can customize it further.

**!It works only when `presenter notes` were activated.**

**An example:**

```
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader
---

<style>
@media print{
  body, html, .remark-slides-area, .remark-notes-area {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    overflow: visible;
    display: inline-block;
    }
    
    p1{ 
    color: red; 
    top: 15cm !important; 
    position: relative !important; 
    left: 1cm !important;
    }
    
}
</style>


# Another Title

### Author

Whatever you want to put on the title slide.

---

Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

<center>
<img src="https://media.baamboozle.com/uploads/images/59332/1598324291_226095" style="width:300px;height:300px;"> 
</center>

???
<p1>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. - Cicero
</p1>
```

**How it looks (A4 paper size):**

[image]

*Tested and printed in Mozilla 104.0.*

P.S. For our fellows, who will read this answer - `presenter notes` are activated by the "P" button.